# rails testing environment broken: routes are undefined methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

Running tests appear to be occuring in a sort of void.
*Note: the following has been tested with a second - pristine - application installation, including identical methods as the first and runs as expected*

test_helper:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require_relative "../config/environment"
require "rails/test_help"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

  fixtures :all

end
```

controller test:

```
require "test_helper"

class LiftsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  setup do
#    @lift = lifts(:one)
    @admin = users(:admin)
    @one = users(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get lifts_url   # line 15
    assert_response :success
  end
```

If the first setup line is uncommented, it generates the first error below (indicating ignorance of fixtures); commented, the second. *the second error is also complete, thereby providing consistent stack elements through both errors*

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `lifts' for #<LiftsControllerTest:0x000000010af1f738>
    /Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:187:in `method_missing'
    /Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb:431:in `method_missing'
  [2nd test]
NameError: undefined local variable or method `lifts_url' for #<LiftsControllerTest:0x000000010aed1420>
    /Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:187:in `method_missing'
    /Users/deploy/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb:431:in `method_missing'
    /Users/deploy/r/elevate/test/controllers/lifts_controller_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:LiftsControllerTest>'
```

The routes whether complete or pared down to the minimum (as follows), still allow the server to be started

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :lifts
end
```

thus excluding a routes syntax or formatting error. The application also runs as expected.
`rails routes` generates:

```
% rails routes
                                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                                       Controller#Action
                                   lifts GET    /lifts(.:format)                                                                                  lifts#index
                                         POST   /lifts(.:format)                                                                                  lifts#create
                                new_lift GET    /lifts/new(.:format)                                                                              lifts#new
                               edit_lift GET    /lifts/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                         lifts#edit
                                    lift GET    /lifts/:id(.:format)                                                                              lifts#show
                                         PATCH  /lifts/:id(.:format)                                                                              lifts#update
                                         PUT    /lifts/:id(.:format)                                                                              lifts#update
                                         DELETE /lifts/:id(.:format)                                                                              lifts#destroy
        turbo_recede_historical_location GET    /recede_historical_location(.:format)                                                             turbo/native/navigation#recedede
[...]
```

Thus the testing environment is 'disconnected' from the application.

The stack trace common elements are highlighting, in both cases, the line with `super` :

```
# assertions/routing.rb:187
      # ROUTES TODO: These assertions should really work in an integration context
      def method_missing(selector, *args, &block)
        if defined?(@controller) && @controller && defined?(@routes) && @routes && @routes.named_routes.route_defined?(selector)
          @controller.public_send(selector, *args, &block)
        else
          super
        end
      end
# integration.rb:431
      # Delegate unhandled messages to the current session instance.
      def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
        if integration_session.respond_to?(method)
          integration_session.public_send(method, *args, &block).tap do
            copy_session_variables!
          end
        else
          super
        end
      end
```

Given the premisse to the question, it appears the testing environment -possibly its references to routes- is corrupted somehow and needs fixing.  But how?

Comment: The first method `lifts` is generated from the fixtures file and has nothing to to with the routes. I would guess that something here is either really screwy with `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` or with your application configuration.

Comment: I would diff all the relevant config files against a fresh install (application.rb, environment.rb, config/environments/test.rb, etc.). There is nothing here in the question which explains it.

Comment: Yes, realised theat it was related to a fixture, which points to an environment problem.  I double check configuration files; the only differences were application.rb which called modules `config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/modules)` and devise initializer which had a different flag `config.reconfirmable`. Commenting out and toggling the boolean did not change the behaviour.  I see no option short of recreating the whole application at this point. since there are only inheritances from `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` ...

Comment: What you can do is stash or commit all your work in GIT - create a new branch and then run the `rails new` command again with the `-f` flag which will overwrite the existing files.  If that fixes the problem you can merge the branch back in and handle the conflicts.